# Prove that the probability of getting at least $k$ heads when using coins that skew more to heads cannot be worse that the alternative

Tags: probability

Let $0 \le p < p' \le 1$. Let $X_i$ be the Bernoulli random variable that takes the value of $1$ with probability of $p$ and zero otherwise. Similarly, let $X'_i$ be the Bernoulli random variable that takes the value of $1$ with probability of $p'$ and zero otherwise. Prove that for any $k$

$$\text{Pr}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge k) \le \text{Pr}(\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i \ge k)$$

**Motivation** This comes up when I am trying to use the Chernoff Bound on Bernoulli random variables, but the probability of the variables are not known, only the upper bound. This is probably "trivial", but I can't seem to recall any reference to this. My attempts at proving this doesn't really go anywhere :(.

**Addendum**
This looks fundamental, so is this a well known problem? If it is, can someone point me to a reference for this (it would be great if it is something that I can use/quote/refer to when writing papers). If there is, I assume this should hold for Poisson trials as well...

Comment: Yes, as can be seen directly by a *coupling* argument: assume that $X_i=\mathbf 1_{U_i\lt p}$ and $X'_i=\mathbf 1_{U_i\lt p'}$ for some i.i.d. $(U_i)$ uniform on $(0,1)$ then $X_i\leqslant X'_i$ almost surely hence $[X_1+\cdots+X_n\geqslant x]\subseteq[X'_1+\cdots+X'_n\geqslant x]$, up to some negligible event, in particular, $\Pr(X_1+\cdots+X_n\geqslant x)\leqslant\Pr(X'_1+\cdots+X'_n\geqslant x)$.

Comment: @Did Ah, indeed, this question is there in the wiki page for coupling. If you answer with either the link or the term I will accept it. Thank you!